# Binding When Property Is Not Observable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is there a best practice way to bind an object's list property when it's not observable? For example, if we have:

```
public class Band
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Musician> Members { get; private set; }
    // other properties here
}
```

If my view model has a `Band` property, and I want my UI to bind to the `Members` property, how are updates to the `Members` property shown on the UI? Members is not observable.

The current thought is to create a DTO that is an exact copy of the `Band` class, but make `Members` an `ObservableCollection`. Then the UI would bind to this DTO. Before the view model closes, it would map the DTO back to the proper `Band` class. This seems like a bit of overhead. Is there a better way?

**Edit - Another Option**

I just had a discussion, in person, with someone about this. The idea is to add an `ObservableCollection` property on the view model. Then, in the constructor of the view model, use the entity to populate the `ObservableCollection`. After the user is done editing, use the updated `ObservableCollection` to reset the `List` on the entity.

Comment: I was going to recommend placing the observable properties in the ViewModel, however see from your edit that you're already on the path to doing that. After all, the ViewModel is meant to model the View, so that should be where observable properties are in a perfect MVVM world :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you could use `ObservableCollection`. You could also use a `BindingList`.

If you do not want to go that route, another other option I see is to make `Band` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then invoke `PropertyChanged` with your `Members` property `name`. That will tell the consuming controls that the list was updated and refresh itself.

The issue going with that route is it may be more of pain to try and figure when to invoke the `PropertyChanged` event than just changing your collection to be `ObservableCollection<T>` or `BindingList<T>`.

Last option is to rebind the collection every time you think it changed or if the control supports it, call the an available `Refresh` method. Something somewhere has to tell the control that the collection changed because they do not periodically check.

Because you tagged this as MVVM, your View should have a `BandViewModel` and an ObservableCollection of `MemberViewModel`s. Everything in a ViewModel is supposed to be bindable and send out notifications when something changed.

Comment: Also there is an option to call `Refresh` on the default view. (ie. `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Members).Refresh()`)

Comment: @zahir True. I'll update my answer to also reflect that.

Comment: If I do your first suggestion (ObservableCollection or BindingList), that means changing my domain entity to adhere to a UI need, so I'd rather not do that. Checking out the rest now.

Comment: About this: rebind the collection every time you think it changed. Do you just mean calling `NotifyPropertyChanged` on `Band`? I tried that and the list doesn't refresh in the UI.

Comment: @BobHorn The thing is though is that normally and standard practice with WPF and MVVM, is you're supposed to have another model to bind against. The entity you use for saving to the database shouldn't be bound against the UI. I mean you can, but you're seeing one of the reasons these are usually broken up. Usually there is a DB object that only is used for retrieving and saving data and then a Business Object that you use for the UI. Normally the BO and DA object map between each other.

Comment: I'm not using the DB object for binding. Our data layer turns the DB entity into our domain entity. It's the domain entity that I'm trying to bind.

Comment: @BobHorn Gotcha on the DB object. I understand now. I would highly look into how to properly do MVVM then. It seems like something is missing or not linked correctly if you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and sending events for "Members" isn't causing the new items to show.

Comment: I just added an edit in my post. Is that an acceptable approach, or am I still missing something?

Comment: @BobHorn That is probably the best approach since you are not wanting to change List on the domain object. It is closer to what would normally be done and is only one extra step.

Comment: Cant recommend the refresh route, it makes the list "stutter" if there are many updates, among other issues. I regret ever going that route.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit rather made the question more confusing. Answer why should be using ObservableCollection.

You should be using ObservableCollection when, well, you want your UI to observe this collection. I mean, when you expect to be modifying this collection (not talking about the item in this collection, but collection as a whole). If you expect to add/remove/sort/filter this collection... if none of these operations is expected, then you are good to bind to IEnumerable also!

Also note, the properties in the underlying item are modified are not has nothing to do with how you are binding the collection as (IEnumerable or Observable). The updates in properties of underlying item are reflected (or not) if the underlying type raises appropriate notification changed event (and implements INotifyPropertyChanged).

Hope that helps!